# swagger not showing any data

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, bearer-token

I am currently using below version of swagger

```
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

if I hit the swagger api from postman I get the data

[image: postman screenshot]

But if I open it from browser, the browser becomes unresponsive

[image: microsoft edge screenshot]

What can I do to make swagger-ui to work??

I tried the owin solution provide in the faq, also tried disabling the validator but did not worked. Below is my swagger configuration :

```
        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "ColloSys.Webapi");
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(x => x.First());
            c.RootUrl(req =>
                req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                req.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/'));
        }).EnableSwaggerUi(x =>
        {
            x.DisableValidator();
        });
```

FYI: I am using it with OWIN, and my web-api has bearer token authentication implementation (if that matters)

** EDIT **

if I open it in firefox it give me error about unresponsive script

[image: firefox]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? If you navigate to http://localhost:8081/swagger/docs/v1, do you see the Swagger spec?

Comment: the ui gets hanged to i am not able to visit the console, that the basic problem - else atleast i would have got to know the code part which is causing this problem

Comment: Looks like you are using Swagger UI v. 2. Can you try [v. 3.0.8](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v3.0.8) instead?

Comment: I had added only this nuget package `id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.5.3"`, not sure what UI version this corresponds to